# Fullcalendar.js add month title below the calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I have been trying to find a way to insert the usual header title of the calendar in a custom UI.

Below is an image of how the calendar layout is -
[image]

I have managed to have the next/prev events by using

`

```
$('#calendar-prev').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
});
$('#calendar-next').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
});
```

`

Likewise I have also managed changing month view and week view by using -

`

```
$('#calendar-month-view').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'month' );
});
$('#calendar-week-view').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'basicWeek' );
});
```

`

So now how do I go about adding the calendar title in between of the next/prev arrows where currently "Month Title" text is manually written?

Comment: You can use var curDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
alert("The current month of the calendar is " + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(curDate, "MMMM")); // Corrected the typo of currDate to curDate but thanks :)

Comment: One Next/Pre button click event fire, after that you can use this sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KushalVora, I'm not really firm with jquery and couldn't find a way to sort this out. Now in my HTML I have `<ul class="schedule-filter-by-date">
           <li><a id="calendar-prev"><i class="ti-arrow-circle-left"></i></a></li>
           <li><span class="calendar-title">MONTH TITLE</span></li>
           <li><a id="calendar-next"><i class="ti-arrow-circle-right"></i></a></li>
          </ul>`. How do I get the title inside span class="calendar-title"?

Comment: Give proper Id to this span

Comment: like this <span class="calendar-title" id="spnMonthTitle">MONTH TITLE</span>

Comment: then                                                       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'); $("#spnMonthTitle").text($.fullCalendar.formatDate(curDate, "MMMM")));

Comment: Use this text instead of alert.

Comment: If possible please mark as answer correct

Comment: I tried using the code as per your instructions HTML - `<span class="calendar-title" id="monthTitle"></span>` JS - `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'); 
  $("#monthTitle").text($.fullCalendar.formatDate(curDate, "MMMM"));
});` But yet I'm not successful, browser console says Uncaught ReferenceError: currDate is not defined :(

Comment: First declare this one

Comment: var curDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');

Comment: then   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'); $("#monthTitle").text($.fullCalendar.formatDate(curDate, "MMMM")); });

Comment: @KushalVora Thanks for helping me but I still can't produce results yet. My JS is - `$(document).ready(function() {
  var curDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'); 
  $("#monthTitle").text($.fullCalendar.formatDate(curDate, "MMMM")); 
});` but console gives error saying **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar.formatDate is not a function**

Comment: Please refer this example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3fL/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the title in between of next/prev I did the following:

JS-

```
    function showMonth () {
    var calendarDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    $('.calendar-title').text(calendarDate.title);
}

$('#calendar-prev').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
    showMonth ();
});

$('#calendar-next').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
    showMonth ();
});
```

HTML -

```
<ul class="schedule-filter-by-date">
    <li><a id="calendar-prev"><i class="ti-arrow-circle-left"></i></a></li>
    <li><span class="calendar-title"></span></li>
    <li><a id="calendar-next"><i class="ti-arrow-circle-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help @Kushal and @Chintan! :)

Comment: Welcom. But please mark the correct sign so that other viewer can get accurate help from this post. It will save time for other person who stuck with same issue. :)

Comment: @ChintanMirani I did, but I can mark it only after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a common function as below.

```
function showMonth () {
    var calendarDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
    $('.calendar-title').html(calendarDate.format('MMMM'));
}
```

Just call it in your navigation and calendar view change click events.

Like

```
$('#calendar-prev').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
    showMonth ();
});
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works fine. But by doing this it produces the date, I was looking how to produce the Title. Thanks for your help I got it by doing `function showMonth () {
    var calendarDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    $('.calendar-title').text(calendarDate.title);
}`